# Changing the sensitivity of a Date filter in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Using the following filter allows me to get information that is current based on the current minute.

```
time: {$gte: new Date()}
```

How could I change this filter to be only sensitive to the current day?  So even if some information has a time field that is a few hours old, but still in the current day, it would get returned.  Here is example documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570e6b2a5bc3c5211a5ad80a"),
    "reason" : "past document",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-04-13T13:46:50Z"),
}    
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570e6b485bc3c5211a5ad80b"),
    "reason" : "future document (today)",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-04-13T18:52:13Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570bcb094fb2e11410e6f74c"),
    "reason" : "fresh appointment",
    "time" : ISODate("2016-04-21T17:04:08Z"),
}
```

Then an expected return would be to return all three documents as they all have a time field that is today and greater.  Currently my filter only returns the bottom two documents because the filter looks at the day, hour, and minute.  Ideally it would only look at the day.

Comment: Please show sample documents with the expected output.

Comment: @user3100115 Great suggestion. Those are added.

Comment: How about `{ time : { "$gte" :  new Date(2016, 04, 13) } }` ?

Comment: @user3100115 It needs to be filtered by the current date.  Not a hard coded value.  chridam was able to help me out.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a date object instance that holds the current date time hours at `00:00:00.000` (milliseconds precision) and use that in you query as:

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

db.collection.find({ "time": { "$gte": start } });
```